# Real time audio input/output in Python with PyAudio

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to get my Raspberry Pi to read some audio input through a basic USB souncard and play it back in real time for 10 seconds, and then print the output with Matplotlib after it's finished. I am using PyAudio in callback mode. Audio recording and playback works fine in Audacity.

```
import pyaudio
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as signal



CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
fulldata = np.array([])
dry_data = np.array([])

def main():
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                input=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(10)
    stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

numpydata = np.hstack(fulldata)
plt.plot(numpydata)
plt.title("Wet")
plt.show()


numpydata = np.hstack(dry_data)
plt.plot(numpydata)
plt.title("Dry")
plt.show()


p.terminate()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    global b,a,fulldata,dry_data,frames 
    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    dry_data = np.append(dry_data,audio_data)
    #do processing here
    fulldata = np.append(fulldata,audio_data)
    return (audio_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

main()
```

After I run my code I can see the the plotted output signal, but it only has very few samples. I can't hear anything through the speakers either while I'm playing. Running the same code on my Windows machine works fine, using the same Python and PyAudio versions.
[image: Audio Output]

I have set my USB audio card as default in etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Your plot shows values from -1 to +1. When you sent them to playback, did you raise the amplitude? I don't hear anything till the amplitude gets around 100, and is good at 5000 for int16 format data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know why your audio is not working.  Perhaps you need to explicitly state the output device index.

This is what I did to get audio out through the RPi audio jack.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# tone.py   play a tone on raspberry pi 
#

import myPyLib   # get control-C handler

import time
import math
import pyaudio
from numpy import linspace,sin,pi,int16

pa = None;
s  = None;

def init_audio(rate=8000):
  global pa,s
  print "init_audio: Create PyAudio object"
  pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
  print "init_audio: Open stream"
  s = pa.open(output=True,
            channels=1,
            rate=rate,
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            output_device_index=0)
  print "init_audio: audio stream initialized"

def close_audio():
  global pa,s
  print "close_audio: Closing stream"
  s.close()
  print "close_audio: Terminating PyAudio Object"
  pa.terminate()


def note(freq, len, amp=5000, rate=8000):
 t = linspace(0,len,len*rate)
 data = sin(2*pi*freq*t)*amp
 return data.astype(int16) # two byte integers

def tone(freq=440.0, tonelen=0.5, amplitude=5000, rate=8000):
  global s
  # generate sound
  tone = note(freq, tonelen, amplitude, rate)

  # play it    
  #print "tone.main(): start playing tone"
  s.write(tone)


# ##### MAIN ######
def main():
  myPyLib.set_cntl_c_handler(close_audio)  # Set CNTL-C handler 

  # open audio channel
  init_audio()

  # play tones forever    
  print "tone.main(): start playing tones"
  while True:
    print "tone.main: tone() 440"
    tone()
    time.sleep(3)
    print "tone.main: tone(261)"
    tone(261,1)
    time.sleep(3)
    print "tone.main: tone(880)"
    tone(880)
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is a 20 second delay opening the stream, but then there is no delay.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/RWP $ ./tone.py
init_audio: Create PyAudio object
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
init_audio: Open stream
init_audio: audio stream initialized
tone.main(): start playing tones
tone.main: tone() 440
tone.main: tone(261)
tone.main: tone(880)
tone.main: tone() 440
tone.main: tone(261)
tone.main: tone(880)
^C
** Control-C Detected
close_audio: Closing stream
close_audio: Terminating PyAudio Object
pi@raspberrypi:~/RWP $
```